# Auto set filter based on another filter in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard with 2 date filters for fiscal month, each reading from different columns.  The primary filter runs most of the charts.  The secondary filter runs only on one table.
I want the secondary filter to automatically match what the user selects in the Primary filter at runtime.

You would think this would be pretty straightforward.  But I cannot find any sort of reasonable answer for this.  The ones I've seen span 4 years and still don't answer the question.

So, to summarize...  If the user chooses (for example) May-2018, and June-2018 in the Primary filter, I want the secondary filter to update with those same selections.

Comment: What you could do is to set the filter as "All using This Data Source", and then delete the second filter.